# How to download files from other dropbox user

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I've managed to create an app on dropbox, and turn out that the app I've created is only able to download my own file not the file on other user dropbox, are there any way to download file on other user dropbox without them to share the files?

Comment: Could you explain more of what you're trying to do? Each user of your app will grant it access to his or her account. The app can then access the files in that account.

Comment: I have one dropbox account which the files are stored in there, so I create an app under that account, let say this account is "Acc A", and I want to other user say "Acc B" be able to download the files under "Acc A", how can this be possible with dropbox API?

Comment: You'd have to share the files from account A. E.g. via [/shares](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shares).

Comment: Seem the only work around currently is sharing the file, but then it will come to a conclusion that the files can be accessed by anyone with link.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Dropbox as a form of version control/repo sharing, it's for the best. If you want to make private repos for free, just use Bitbucket. There a strong chance you'll lose files in the Dropbox exchange as well (which is probably what's happening here).

Comment: I don't see how this answer relates to the question asked.

Comment: I am still trying to use Dropbox, as the requirement for now. Maybe you pointing to a correct keyword, I haven't look into file sharing with dropbox api

Comment: Whoops,  my bad. I think i made a pretty poor assumption here.